# Ask someone's help to explain the performance issue of C# code

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am a C# developer and I am training my coding and algorithm skills on LeetCode.
And now I am handling the problem 5: [longest palindromic substring](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/).
I want someone can explain the reason.
My solution **version 1** to this problem was:

```
public string LongestPalindrome(string s)
{
    // Step 0: Handles invalid or special cases.
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ||
        s.Length == 1 ||
        s.Distinct().Count() == 1 ||
        s.Reverse().SequenceEqual(s))
        {
            return s;
        }

        if (s.Length == 2)
        {
            return s.First().Equals(s.Last()) ? s : s.First().ToString();
        }

        if (s.Distinct().Count() == s.Length)
        {
            return s.First().ToString();
        }

        // Step 1: Handles normal cases.
        var longestPalindromeSubstring = string.Empty;

        for (var index = 0; index < s.Length && s.Length - index > longestPalindromeSubstring.Length; index++)
        {
            var currentChar = s[index];
            var currentCharLastIndex = s.LastIndexOf(currentChar);

            if (index == currentCharLastIndex)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(longestPalindromeSubstring) ||
                        longestPalindromeSubstring.Length > 1)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                longestPalindromeSubstring = currentChar.ToString();
            }

            var currentCharIndexes = new Stack<int>();

            for (var nextIndex = index + 1; nextIndex <= currentCharLastIndex; nextIndex++)
            {
                if (s[nextIndex] == currentChar)
                {
                    currentCharIndexes.Push(nextIndex);
                }
            }

            while (currentCharIndexes.Any())
            {
                var relatedIndex = currentCharIndexes.Pop();
                var possibleStr = s.Substring(index, relatedIndex - index + 1);
                var reversedPossibleStr = new string(possibleStr.Reverse().ToArray());

                if (!possibleStr.Equals(reversedPossibleStr) ||
                    possibleStr.Length < longestPalindromeSubstring.Length ||
                    possibleStr.Equals(longestPalindromeSubstring))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                longestPalindromeSubstring = possibleStr;
            }
        }

        return longestPalindromeSubstring;
    }
```

However this solution above was failed to pass the LeetCode validation since the issue: Time Limit Exceeded.
Then I just made a small update, and the solution **version 2** passed, the changed part was only adding ***ToCharArray()*** method before invoking Reverse() method:

```
var reversedPossibleStr = new string(possibleStr.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());

if (!possibleStr.Equals(reversedPossibleStr) ||
     possibleStr.Length < longestPalindromeSubstring.Length ||
     possibleStr.Equals(longestPalindromeSubstring))
{
     continue;
}
…………
```

But I am not sure the reason why it can work, I just guessed that the data in an array will be arranged in a sequence memory space, it may help to improve the performance, could someone explain more detail.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: One small thing you can see directly: you are counting all unique chars twice: `s.Distinct().Count()`, use a variable. `s.Reverse().SequenceEqual(s)` is also quite expensive, try to avoid this early check and handle it with your normal logic.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I will update my code to make it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Reverse` method uses [`EnumerableHelpers.ToArray`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/EnumerableHelpers.cs,18) to fetch the count of the input enumerable. If the enumerable doesn't implement `ICollection<T>` interface, it will use a [list-like approach](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/EnumerableHelpers.cs,61) to creates an array which will extend the array many times. Unfortunately `string` doesn't implement `ICollection<char>`, though it knows how many characters it contains, so `string.Reverse()` is slower than `string.ToCharArray().Reverse()`.